# Problem sending mail from PHP page using GMail's SMTP server

Tags: php, smtp

I'm using the script in the marked answer of this thread:
[Send email using the GMail SMTP server from a PHP page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/712392/send-email-using-gmail-smtp-server-from-php-page)
When I use this script on my hostgator based site, it works perfectly. However, mails are not being sent from the GoDaddy hosted site. Both have versions upwards of PHP 5.2.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have a problem sending mail and you get the error.

Usually I'm trying to send email manually using telnet. so try the following on the server console from command line:

1) telent [smtp server] 25
When you are connected type the following:
2) HELO [our full qualified domain name as it appers in email]

3) MAIL FROM: [FromAddress@yourdomail.com]

4) RCPT TO: [recipient@recipientdomain.com]

5) DATA

type any text.

6) click enter and then click ".".

You will see if your server is sending mail or returning you any email.

You can read about those commands here 
http://www.yuki-onna.co.uk/email/smtp.html